# Starting git-cola in branch view

Tags: git, git-cola

The majority of times I start `git-cola` I go through the sequence **Branch** → **Visualize Current Branch...** (or **Visualize All Branches...**).

Is there a way to directly launch one of those views from the command line?

```
$ git-cola --version
cola version 2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, incidentally I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344004/616460) to an unrelated question, where I discovered `git-cola` adds a `cola` module to `git` (`git cola ...`, `git help cola`). Then I checked through `git help cola` but didn't see what I was looking for.

But then I noticed the viewer had `gitk` at the end of the title bar.

So I just typed `gitk` on the command line and it worked. Not too experienced with `git` and related tools, so I didn't know that existed.

So to answer my initial question more specifically (at least for Git Cola 2.5):

- **Branch → Visualize Current Branch...**: `gitk`
- **Branch → Visualize All Branches...**: `gitk --all`
- Bonus: Visualize a specific other branch: `gitk <branchname>`
- Bonus: **View → DAG...**: `git dag`

I do not know if `gitk` came with `git-cola`, or if it's its own thing, or really how I got it. Same deal with the DAG tool.